# efficient result display for python 3

Tags: python-3.x

i have written a program that searches every file/folder that is contained within its current folder for fikes with a certain name. i create a dictionary with a path and a list of names within that folder.
i am looking for an effective way to display that after the program is run. it cant display through the terminal as i plan to compile it and rin it elsewhere. what would be a good way of showing the result? my original plan was to make, edit, open and delete a tempory txt file, but i cant find a way to open it to make it visible to the user.
thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what kind of answer you want. Where else are you going to compile and run it, and what output devices does that place have which you could use? Use one of those..

Comment: Would opening notepad from python be a solution?

Comment: tesselatingHeckler, im planning on compiling it to run on windows. im unsure of how to use any other form of output except of printing to the terminal. c2huc it might be, but i dont know how to open it to make it visible, only how to open to edit

Comment: What's wrong with printing to the terminal on Windows? Tons of programs do that. But it sounds like you're asking how to write a graphical interface (GUI) and that's too broad to be on-topic for StackOverflow, but there are some answers and discussion here - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/34768/28443

Comment: if i compiled it and ran it on a computer without pycharm (what i use) and printed it to the terminal, eould it automatically pop up? or woyld i need to open and run from the terminal, or any such combination?